# Match last occuring enclosing outer brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried now for three hours to construct the following regex match without much success. I have the following two strings:

```
This is a test string to illustrate the problem (example) in complex matching logic (Work / not working (in this case) to match this last occurring bracket closure)
```

and

```
Simpler version of the string (Matchable in any easy way)
```

I would like to define a `str.match()` that matches this last part of the strings above. Resulting in:

```
Work / not working (in this case) to match this last occurring bracket closure
```

and

```
Matchable in any easy way
```

Any good way to achieve this? Sadly the data is highly volatile that a strong Regex is much rather preferred instead of long functional logic. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can’t match arbitrarily deeply nested parentheses with regular expressions; sorry. Building a parser isn’t hard, though. To make sure: you’re trying to find the last parenthesized section in a string?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. Yes, correct. I hoped there is a way to use matching groups. Sadly my experience with regex hits a wall here. The problem lies in a huge and volatile dataset of unstructured data for which regex is much much more efficient to use for string manipulation than a functional approach.

Comment: How did you determine that regular expressions were more efficient? Did you try a different approach? Maybe it might be better to post that here and ask for help improving its efficiency.

Comment: As I understand your scepticism, I should clarify that this was not to be understood as a general statement about Javascript (aka yet another efficiency debate). It is more applicable to our specific set up of node.js and the workings of custom transpilers that move stuff to C modules. So some functional limitations and the observation that on the fly string manipulation in V8s regex engine seems to be resilient and very performant. Of course, if it can not solely be done in regex, we'd need to use additional string manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t match arbitrarily deeply nested parentheses with regular expressions. Some regular expression engines have been extended in such a way that they can parse that kind of grammar, but JavaScript’s has not; you’ll need to match manually.

```
function lastParenthesizedSubstring(text) {
    var end = text.lastIndexOf(')');
    var i = end - 1;
    var nesting = 1;

    while (nesting > 0) {
        if (i < 0) {
            // Parenthesis imbalance! You may want to throw
            // an exception or something.
            return null;
        }

        var c = text.charAt(i);

        if (c === ')') {
            nesting++;
        } else if (c === '(') {
            nesting--;
        }

        i--;
    }

    return text.substring(i + 2, end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is really impractical for this. Your regex would have to be extremely long, and will always have it's limitations. I *really* recommend using some parser. I like to use [balanced.js](https://github.com/icodeforlove/balanced.js).

```
var lastItem = balanced.matches({
    source: string,
    open: '(',
    close: ')'
}).map(function (match) {
    return string.substr(match.index + match.head.length, match.length - match.head.length - match.tail.length);
}).filter(function (a, b, c) {
    return b === c.length - 1;
})[0] || "";
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YR7y5/6/)**

Results:

> Simpler version of the string (Matchable in any easy way)
>
> Matchable in any easy way

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't think of anything better. This also isn't 100% RegEx. Assume `string` is your string

```
var matches = string.match(/(\([^(]*\))/g),
    result  = matches[matches.length-1].substring(0, matches[matches.length-1].length - 1);
```

Limitations

- Only allows one level deep parentheses
- Only can of one, one level deep parentheses

Comment: This only matches “(in this case) to match this last occurring bracket closure”.